# limit with nested power of $x$

Tags: limits

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}-x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}{(x-1)^6}$$

Try:: I try to solve it using Binomial Index for fraction

$\displaystyle x^x=\bigg[1+(x-1)\bigg]^x=1+x(x-1)+\frac{x(x-1)^2}{2}+\cdots $

Did not know how can i solve it,

Could some help me , thanks

Comment: Just a bit curious where such an expression arises. Which kind of application?

Comment: l'Hopital may be a possibility, but it's not going to be pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=x-1\to 0$ then
$$x^s-1=e^{s\ln(1+t)}=st+O(st^2)$$
Hence 
$$x^x-x=x(x^{x-1}-1)=(1+t)(t^2+O(t^3))=t^2+O(t^3)$$
and
$$x^{x^x}-x^x=x^x(x^{x^x-x}-1)=(1+O(t))\left( (t^2+O(t^3))t+O((t^2+O(t^3))t^2)\right)=t^3+O(t^4).$$
In the same way, we get
$$\frac{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}-x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}{(x-1)^6}=\frac{t^6+O(t^7)}{t^6}\to 1.$$